# Stochastic process entropy rate limit

Tags: limits, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, entropy, stationary-processes

How do we show that where $(X_i)_{i\geq1}$ is a stochastic process with finite state space $X$, that if one of the following limits exist, then also other exist and all three coincide?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(X_1,...,X_n)}{n}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n})}{n}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n} | X_1,...,X_k)}{n}$$

I understand how we are able to prove that for a stationary process $H(X) = H'(X)$, where $H'(X) = \sum^{n}_{i = 1}\frac{H(X_i|X_{i-1},...,X_1)}{n}$ , but am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: so the question is for stationary processes ?

Comment: @AlexTP essentially, yes. It is the entropy rate which is part of the stationary processes, and based on the second and third limit, which are time-invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is for stochastic process $\left\lbrace X_i \right\rbrace$ which is **stationary**.

\begin{eqnarray}
H_1 &= &\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(X_1,...,X_n)}{n} \\
H_2 &= &\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n})}{n} \\
H_3 &= &\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{H(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n} | X_1,...,X_k)}{n}
\end{eqnarray}

The core of proof is $H_0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} H(X_n|X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)$.

### 1) $H_0$ does exist

$$0 < H(X_{n+1} | X_n, \cdots, X_1) \leq H(X_{n+1} | X_n, \cdots, X_2) =  H(X_n | X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)$$
where the first inequality is from the fact that entropy is non negative, the second one is because adding $X_1$ reduces uncertainty, and the equality is from stationary property.

$H(X_n|X_{n-1}, \cdots, X_1)$ is a non negative decreasing function wrt $n$, thus $H_0$ exists.

### 2) $H_1= H_0$

By the chain rule,
$$\frac{1}{n} H(X_1,...,X_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i = 1}H(X_i|X_{i-1},...,X_1)$$

Use [Cesàro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) with proven $H_0$ is the limit of $H(X_n|X_{n-1},...,X_1)$, we have $H_1 = H_0$. (I can add the proof of Cesàro mean if you want).

### 2) $H_2= H_1$

By definition of stationary process, $H(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n}) = H(X_1,...,X_n)$.

### 3) $H_3= H_0$

$$\frac{H(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+n} | X_1,...,X_k)}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum^{k+n}_{i = k+1}H(X_i|X_{i-1},...,X_1)$$

Always [Cesàro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean), when $n \to \infty$, the limit of LHS is $H_3$, and the limit of RHS is $H_0$.

### Conclusion,

all roads lead to $H_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will definitely help in my future analysis. I will get back in case I don't manage to rewrite the Cesaro mean, but hopefully that won't be the case.

Comment: What changes if the process is not stationary?

Comment: @今天春天 if the process is not stationary, the limits do not exist without supplemental assumptions.

Comment: And with supplemental assumptions you mean...?