# How to proof stochastic process without stationary property?

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_i)_{i\ge1}$ be stochstic process with finite space $X$. Show that if one of the limits

[image]

exists, then also the other limits exist and all 3 coincide. H is the entropy.

---

I have found a proof (see underneath), but this one is only for stochastic processes. Is there a possibility, without assuming the process is stationary?

see $\rightarrow$ [Stochastic process entropy rate limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268758/stochastic-process-entropy-rate-limit)

Comment: Can you define the $H(\cdot)$ function in this question so it is not necessary to refer to another one?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate